# Specifying the qplot "fill" argument in an r function

Tags: r

I'm just starting to use R, and want to create a generic function where I can specify the "fill" argument for the the `qplot()` function.

```
graph_search <- function(group) {
    qplot(time, data=subset, geom="density", fill=path, alpha=I(.5))
}
graph_search("path");
graph_search("code"); # does not work
```

Ideally I would replace the `fill=path` with `fill=group`, in the same way it works with:

```
data_max <- function(size = 5) {
    print(tail(subset[order(subset$time),], n=size))
}
data_max(10);
```

---

### Background

I'm using this to look at some WebServer logs, where each record (request) has a `time` (how long it took to execute in seconds), `path` (the URL requested without the query string), response `code` (e.g. 200, 301), the ID of the `user` logged in, etc.

The `subset` variable is created with a query such as:

```
subset <- subset(data, code != 302 & time > 0.2 & path!="/not/this/path/")
subset <- subset(data, code != 302 & grepl("^/admin/", path) & time > 0)
subset <- subset(data, code == 500)
```

And these work well with:

```
graph_frequency <- function() {
    # hist(subset$time, xlab="time", col="lightblue", main="Web 1")
    qplot(time, data=subset, geom="density", fill=code, alpha=I(.5))
}
graph_history <- function() {
    # plot(time ~ timestamp, data=subset, type='h', xlab='date', ylab='time')
    plot(subset$timestamp, subset$time, type='h', xlab='date', ylab='time')
}
```

---

### Extra info

And while this isn't relevant to the question (but feel free to comment on how to improve this), the Apache config uses:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u [%{LOG_INFO}n] [%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t] [%D/%{TIME_INFO}n] \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" inc_info
```

With the non-Apache variables coming from PHP:

```
if (function_exists('apache_note')) {
    apache_note('LOG_INFO', USER_ID);
    apache_note('TIME_INFO', number_format(round((microtime(true) - FRAMEWORK_START), 4), 4));
}
```

Where R is started with:

```
library("stringr")
library("ggplot2")
```

And the access log is parsed with:

```
data_load <- function(log_path) {

    data = read.table(log_path, sep=" ")

    data$timestamp = as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(data[,5], data[,6]), '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'))
    data$timings <- str_match(data[,7], "\\[([0-9]*)/(.*)\\]")[,c(2,3)]
    data$info <- str_match(data[,4], "\\[(.*)\\]")[,2]
    data$request <- str_match(data[,8], "([A-Z]+) (/.*) HTTP")[,c(2,3)]

    data = cbind(
        timestamp = data[13],
        apache = data[,14][,1],
        time = data[,14][,2],
        ip = data[,1],
        info = data[,15],
        method = data[,16][,1],
        url = data[,16][,2],
        code = data[,9],
        size = data[,10],
        referrer = data[,11],
        agent = data[,12])

    data$time <- as.numeric(as.character(data$time))
    data$info <- as.numeric(as.character(data$info))
    data$code <- as.character(data$code)
    data$path <- gsub("\\?.*", "", data$url)

    # Drop apache/referrer/agent
    data = data[,-c(2,10,11)]

    # Drop url (optional)
    data = data[,-c(6)]

    return(data)

}
```

Comment: (1) Switch from `qplot` to `ggplot`, (2) See `aes_string()`.

Comment: Thanks @joran, but may I ask if it is possible with qplot (I was under the impression is was just a wrapper for ggplot)...
group="code";
m <- ggplot(subset, aes(x = time))
m + geom_density(aes_string(fill=group), alpha=I(.5))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @joran, this seems to work:

```
graph_search <- function(group) {
    ggplot(subset, aes(x = time)) + geom_density(aes_string(fill=group), alpha=I(.5))
}
```

Which uses `ggplot` directly, rather than the shorthand `qplot` (aka "quick plot").